# Exclude multiple fields from datadump in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there a way to exclude fields from different tables while taking DB dump. I could only find to exclude a model completely. (I am using postgresql). any help is appreciated..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.   I would grab a copy of dumpdata.py from the Django source and put it into your project and customize it.  It would not be too hard to extend it to either use a custom manager for dumping or extend the exclude to support app.model.field.

That sounds like a generally useful extension.

Comment: sorry for the late rply, i just came across SOUTH n i think it wud be helpful

Comment: Yes.  Definitely use south if migrations are why you are doing data dumps!

Answer (score 1):

One possible trick is to define a new model with a subset of fields and set `managed=False` and override `db_table` fields in `Meta`.

It is also possible to avoid repetition defining common fields through common abstract parent model.

```
class CommonBase(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ModelX(CommonBase):
    pass

class SubsmetOfModelX(CommonBase):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'app_label_modelx'
```

Drawbacks of this approach might be:

- Always need to exclude at least one model of two above during `dumpdata`, otherwise `dumpdata` will include duplicate objects.
- `loaddata` for `SubsetOfModelX` will fail if there are any `null=False` fields on `ModelX` that are not on the subset model.

Answer (score -1):

You can dump it into a JSON file and then use Notepad++ or equivalent to remove every line that has your field_name. Works for me, and very quick too. Make sure your field name is unique so that it will not remove other rows.

Comment: with a vim it could be true